# Temporary files stays in linux after an attempt to delete

Tags: java, linux, fuse

I am writing a java servlet which downloads file from client and move it to some specific location. After move I delete the downloaded file. Sometimes linux creates .fuse_hidden______ named files. They stays there until I restart my server process. After download I do close all the opened streams. It usually happens on mounted USB flash drives.

Here is my code snippet

```
    try{
           ...
           inputStream = new RandomAccessFile(new File(sourcePath), "r");
           inputChannel = inputStream.getChannel();
           ....
        }
    finally{
           inputChannel.close(); 
           inputStream .close();
       }
    new File(sourcePath).delete();
```

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions? If an exception is thrown, the file won't be deleted because that statement is outside the try, catch, finally block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means there is still at least one open file handle on the file. When the last handle has been closed then the hidden file will be deleted.

You say that they disappear when you kill your server, therefore your server still has at least one handle open on to the file. You can use the `lsof` command to prove that it is indeed your server that has the open handle.

Check very carefully that you are closing all open streams on to the file in your java in both the success and exception cases.

Comment: Looked at the download code, it had the following lines for closing the downloaded file :
destinationOutputStream.close();    destinationOutputStream.flush();

Can this be a reason for those fuse files, flush() is being called after close() ?

Comment: A closed stream can't be flushed so that code is a problem as it stands. After you fix this logic error does the original handle problem go away?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It seems like that fix has resolved the issue. Haven't seen those .fuse files after few hours of tests. Thanks!